# Ableton Live 9 (or 10) Lite Vocoder

Tags: windows-10, ableton-live

I've been using Ableton Live 9 Lite a little for several months, and recently updated to Ableton Live 10 Lite.  I can't find the built-in Ableton vocoder shown in video tutorials in either of these versions.  Does anyone know whether the Ableton Live Lite software has the built-in vocoder?  Thank you very much! ::)

Answer (score 0):

- Ableton Live 10 Vocoder is **not** available in **Lite** Edition and Intro
  Edition.
- Ableton Live 10 Vocoder is available in Standard Edition and Suite
  Edition.
- Ableton Lite is slightly more restricted than the Intro version.
- For detailed comparisons between Intro, Standard and Suite Editions
  see the corresponding official page.
  https://www.ableton.com/en/live/compare-editions/
- For detailed list of features included in Live 10 Lite visit
  https://www.ableton.com/en/products/live-lite/features/ (As you can see Vocoder is not listed there, thus it is not available in Lite Edition of Live)